# What is the main difference between register_chrdev() and alloc_chedev()?

Tags: linux-device-driver

```
register_chrdev(unsigned int major,const char *name,const struct file_oprations *fops)
```

and

```
alloc_chedev(dev_t devid,unsigned int fmi,unsigned int nod,const char *name)
```

The small difference which i knew was that `register_chrdev` will allocate 256 minor no. associated with a device whereas `alloc_chrdev` asks for no. of devices and first minor no. and will allocate accordingly.

Comment: Please put some punctuations and separate sentences.
It is very hard to read your question

Comment: Presumably, you mean the `alloc_chrdev_region` function. One big difference is that the functions that end in `_region` (i.e. `alloc_chrdev_region` and `register_chrdev_region`) do not call `cdev_alloc` at all (so the driver has to call `cdev_alloc` or `cdev_init`), whereas `register_chrdev` and `__register_chrdev` do call `cdev_alloc` (so the driver does not need to do so).

Comment: For the two functions that do not call `cdev_alloc`, namely `register_chrdev_region` and `alloc_chrdev_region`, the main difference is that `register_chrdev_region` registers a specific range of device numbers, whereas `alloc_chrdev_region` searches for a suitable range of unregistered device numbers and registers it.

Answer (score 3):

register_chrdev used to register a major number for character devices. User has to give the major number to the API for respective device.

alloc_chrdev used to allocates a range of char device numbers. The major number will be chosen dynamically and returned along with the first minor number.

Comment: There is no necessity that user has to give the major number because if you give '0' to the first argument of register_chrdev than kernel will give you a major number(the return of register_chrdev will be the major number).